# HAXM Installer for Android SDK

Tags: android-studio

I recently downloaded the Android Studio, but am having some trouble getting it running.  Anytime I attempt to run the emulator, I get the following error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I am trying to run this on a Lenovo Yoga. When I look in the Android SDK manager, it shows that the HAXM Installer has been downloaded, but the file path it gives doesn't seem to actually exist on my computer.  Any ideas on a fix would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not real computer savvy, so please attempt to dumb down your answers.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the stand alone installer
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

Comment: That seemed to fix it.  Much appreciated, Codecats!