# Cannot start emulator Intel HAXM error

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I am new to Android Studio. I am still receiving that familiar error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I checked the SDK Manager, and the box for HAXM is already checked and installed.
So I attempted to reinstall it manually under the `extras` folder in the SDK directory, but the problem is that `intelhaxm-android.exe` doesn't run even with administrator credentials. I opened and authorized it, but nothing happened.
I also tried the Intel stand alone installer, and that gives the same result.
Please help!

Comment: Is it the same as the standalone one here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698507/haxm-installer-for-android-sdk?rq=1

Comment: Dear OP:  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay.  But, about your question:  [What else have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)  Have you tried Sysinternals Process Monitor?  Does `intelhaxm-android.exe` use Windows Installer in the background, and if so, have you tried to find some way to get it to log?  Please [edit] your question and tell us what you've tried.  Each time you edit it, it'll be bumped to the top of the homepage, which is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. I could fix it with disabling Hyper-V on my Windows Machine.

Go to Settings -> Turn windows features on or off -> uncheck Hyper-V

After rebooting the system intelhaxm was running.